# getting multiple average columns in vapor 4 fluent

Tags: swift, postgresql, vapor, vapor-fluent

I am working on a project in vapor and I would like to calculate the average of multiple columns,
but I can't figure out how to do it. I can get the average of one column like this:

```swift
let runCount = try await RunCount.query(on: req.db)
                   .filter(\.$player.$id == "Unique string")
                   .average(\.$interval1)
```

I have tried to parse more parameters to the `average` function without luck and I have also tried to call the `average` function multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluent can't do averages across multiple columns, primarily because the underlying syntax for each DB is so different. You could write a custom extension or drop down to raw SQL to do it instead.

Comment: using raw sql is what i ended up doing. thanks